# A summation identity

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, induction, summation-method

I have encountered this identity in Page 616 of *Mathematical Methods for Students of Physics and Related Fields* (Second Edition) by Sadri Hassani:
$$
\sum_{m = 0}^{n}\left(-1\right)^{m}\,
{\left(\,{2n + 2m}\,\right)!
\over \left(\,{n + m}\,\right)!\,\left(\,{n - m}\,\right)!\,
\left(\,{2m}\,\right)!} = \left(\,{-4}\,\right)^n
$$.
I don't know how one can obtain it directly, however, I tried to prove it by induction.

Thus, for $n = 1$, the identity is valid. If we assume its validity for $n$, we have to show that

$\sum_{m = 0}^{n + 1} (-1)^m \frac{(2n + 2m + 2)!}{(n + m + 1)! (n - m + 1)! (2 m)!} = (-4)^{n + 1}$.

The thing that comes to one's mind is that to separate the ($n + 1$)th term in the left-hand side of the above, and write it as

$(-1)^{n + 1} \frac{(4n + 4)!}{(2n + 2)! (2n + 2)!} + \sum_{m = 0}^{n} (-1)^m \frac{(2n + 2m + 2)!}{(n + m + 1)! (n - m + 1)! (2 m)!}$,

which with a little simplification, it becomes

$(-1)^{n + 1} \frac{(4n + 4)!}{(2n + 2)! (2n + 2)!} + 2 \sum_{m = 0}^{n} (-1)^m \frac{(2n + 2m + 1) (2n + 2m)!}{(n - m + 1) (n + m)! (n - m)! (2 m)!}$.

It seems to me that one cannot simplify it more in order to be able to use the assumption; one could divide $\frac{2n + 2m + 1}{n - m + 1}$ but it doesn't seem to lead anywhere. Any help to proceed from here is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very different kind of answer than what you want. This is a sum of [hypergeometric terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_identity), and therefore in principle your identity is algorithmic to verify.

If we let $S(n)$ be your sum, then [Zeilberger's algorithm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZeilbergersAlgorithm.html) (with, say, `SumTools[Hypergeometric][Zeilberger](S, n, m, E)` in Maple) returns the result
$$
[E + 4,\ {\frac {m \left( 2\,m-1 \right)  \left( -1 \right) ^{m} \left( 2\,n+2\,m \right) !\,
 \left( 8\,n+6 \right) }{ \left( -n+m-1 \right)  \left( n+m \right) !\, \left( n-m \right) !\,
 \left( 2\,m \right) !\, \left( 2\,{n}^{2}+3\,n+1 \right) }}],
$$
where $E$ is the shift operator $ES(n) = S(n + 1)$. This signifies that $S(n)$ satisfies the recurrence $(E + 4) S(n) = 0$, i.e., $S(n + 1) = -4S(n)$. (The second part is to "verify" the results of the algorithm, if you were so inclined.) Since it is easy to check that $S(0) = 1$, it follows that $S(n) = (-4)^n$ for $n \geq 0$.

---

Here's a more human approach, though still not "directly" evaluating the sum. I liberally use generating functions - see [generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/DownldGF.html) for a nice introduction.

Note that your sum is $$S(n) = \sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^k {2(n + k) \choose n + k} {n + k \choose n - k} = \sum_{k \leq n} (-1)^k {2(n + k) \choose n + k} {n + k \choose n - k}$$ for $n \geq 0$. If we shift the summation variable back by $n$, then $$S(n) = \sum_{k \leq 2n} (-1)^{k - n} {2k \choose k}{k \choose 2n - k}.$$

There is one obvious simplification to try here: $(-1)^k {2k \choose k} = 4^k {-1/2 \choose k}$, which gives

$$S(n) = (-1)^n \sum_{k \leq 2n} 4^k {-1/2 \choose k}{k \choose 2n - k}.$$

The remaining hard part is the sum. The $2n$ is unimportant now (only $2n$ appears in the sum, never $n$ by itself), so let's define

$$R(n) = \sum_{k \leq n} 4^k {-1/2 \choose k} {k \choose n - k}.$$

If we have $R(n)$, then $S(n) = (-1)^n R(2n)$. [There is probably an easy way to evaluate $R(n)$, but I haven't found it yet.]

Let's stop thinking so hard, define $$R(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} R(n) x^n,$$ and blindly manipulate some sums:

\begin{align*}
    R(x) &= \sum_{n \geq 0} \sum_{k \leq n} 4^k {-1/2 \choose k} {k \choose n - k} x^n \\
         &= \sum_{k \geq 0} \sum_{n \geq k} 4^k {-1/2 \choose k} {k \choose n - k} x^n \\
         &= \sum_{k \geq 0} 4^k {-1/2 \choose k} \sum_{n \geq k} {k \choose n - k} x^n \\
         &= \sum_{k \geq 0} 4^k {-1/2 \choose k} \sum_{n \geq 0} {k \choose n} x^{n + k} \\
         &= \sum_{k \geq 0} 4^k {-1/2 \choose k} x^k (1 + x)^k \\
         &= \sum_{k \geq 0} [4x(1 + x)]^k {-1/2 \choose k} \\
         &= (1 + 4x(1 + x))^{-1/2} \\
         &= \frac{1}{1 + 2x} \\
         &= \sum_{n \geq 0} (-2)^n x^n.
\end{align*}

Therefore $R(n) = (-2)^n$, which finally gives $S(n) = (-1)^n R(2n) = (-4)^n$.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer. I need time to understand it. Is it also possible to prove it by mathematical induction?

Comment: @Novice Sorry for using so many techniques that might be new to you - I was just throwing everything at the wall to see what would stick :) Induction would probably work if you had the insight to see what manipulations were necessary. I think the manipulations are probably very messy, which is why I've tried other methods here.

Comment: A question: The last term in the formula after the sentence, "If we shift the summation variable back by $n$", shouldn't be ${k \choose - k}$ as we are subtracting $n$ from the argument of the sum? Also, the dummy index now runs from $n$ to $2n$? Where am I making mistake?

Comment: @Novice In general, you can write $\sum_{k \leq n} f(k) = \sum_{k - c \leq n} f(k - c)$ for any integer $c$, and $k - c \leq n$ is equivalent to $k \leq n + c$. I did this with $c = n$, so ${2(n + k) \choose n + k}$ became ${2k \choose k}$, and the range went from $n$ to $n + n = 2n$. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks. What about the other factor? Why doesn't $n + k \choose n - k$ become $k \choose - k$?

Comment: @Novice When $k \to k - n$, you get $n + k \to n + (k - n) = k$ and $n - k \to n - (k - n) = 2n - k$. Careful about the minus signs in the lower index!

Comment: Oh! I'm too careless. Thanks!

Comment: Another question: In $S(n)$ the index $k$ varies from $n$ to $2n$, i.e., $n \leq k \leq 2n$, and in $R(n)$ it varies from $0$ to $n$, i.e., $0 \leq k \leq n$. Then, you have written $S(n) = (-1)^n R(2n)$, however if we replace $n$ by $2n$ in $R(n)$ now we have $0 \leq k \leq 2n$, but for the original $S(n)$ we had $n \leq k \leq 2n$. So, where am I making a mistake?

Comment: @Novice The summation indices don't actually matter here, because everything outside of the "natural" range is zero. For example, if $k > n$ in $R(n)$, then ${k \choose n - k} = 0$ (by definition). Similarly, if $0 \leq k < n$ in the shifted $S(n)$, then ${k \choose 2n - k} = 0$ (because $2n - k > k \geq 0$), and if $k < 0$, then ${-1/2 \choose k} = 0$. You could write all of these sums as being over all the integers and forget about bounds completely. This saves a lot of headaches :)

Answer (score 1):

**Introductory  remark.** The  proof  that  I show  below  is not  the
simplest possible,  but it does illustrate  residue techniques. Seeing
that we  have two  very different  methods documented  on the  page it
almost  became a  challenge whether  we  could prove  it by  residues,
thereby adding a  third method, for a Rosetta stone  effect. The heart
of the proof is  in the first half, the second  half is concerned with
proving  that  a  certain  pole  does not  contribute  to  the  count.
Possibly this part can be simplified.  It is hoped that the reader may
gain by this additional perspective on this interesting sum.

We seek to show that

$$\sum_{m=0}^n 
(-1)^m {2n+2m\choose n+m} {n+m\choose n-m} = (-1)^n 2^{2n}.$$

The LHS is

$$[z^n] (1+z)^{n}
\sum_{m=0}^n (-1)^m {2n+2m\choose n+m} (1+z)^m z^m.$$

The coefficient extractor enforces the upper limit of the sum and we
may continue with

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{n+1}} 
\sum_{m\ge 0} (-1)^m {2n+2m\choose n+m} (1+z)^m z^m \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{n+1}}
\\ \times \sum_{m\ge 0} (-1)^m \frac{1}{w^m} \frac{1}{(1-w)^m} (1+z)^m z^m
\; dw \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{1+z(1+z)/w/(1-w)}
\; dw \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{n}}
\frac{1}{w(1-w)+z(1+z)}
\; dw \; dz
\\ = - \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{n}}
\frac{1}{(w+z)(w-(1+z))}
\; dw \; dz.$$

The contribution from the pole at $w=-z$ is

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{(-1)^n}{z^{n}} \frac{1}{(1+z)^{n}}
\frac{1}{1+2z} \; dz
\\ = \frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{2n+1}} \frac{1}{1+2z} \; dz 
= (-1)^n [z^{2n}] \frac{1}{1+2z} = (-1)^n (-1)^{2n} 2^{2n}
\\ = \bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
(-1)^n 2^{2n}.}$$

This is the claim. We will document a choice of $\gamma$ and $\epsilon$
so that $w=0$ and $w=-z$ are the only poles inside the contour (pole at
$w=1$ not included, nor the pole at $w=1+z.$)

Now we have for the pole at $w=0$

$$-\frac{1}{(w+z)(w-(1+z))} =
\frac{1}{1+2z} \frac{1}{w+z}
- \frac{1}{1+2z} \frac{1}{w-(1+z)}
\\ = \frac{1}{z} \frac{1}{1+2z} \frac{1}{1+w/z}
+ \frac{1}{1+z} \frac{1}{1+2z} \frac{1}{1-w/(1+z)}.$$

We get from the first piece

$$- \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{n+2}} 
\frac{1}{1+2z} \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {q+n-1\choose n-1} 
(-1)^{n-1-q} \frac{1}{z^{n-1-q}} \; dz
\\ = - \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {q+n-1\choose n-1} 
(-1)^{n-1-q}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{2n+1-q}} 
\frac{1}{1+2z} \; dz
\\ = - \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {q+n-1\choose n-1} 
(-1)^{n-1-q} \sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p} (-1)^{2n-q-p} 2^{2n-q-p}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {q+n-1\choose n-1} 2^{n-q}
\sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p} (-1)^{n-p} 2^{n-p}
\\ = (-1)^n \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {q+n-1\choose n-1} 2^{n-q}.$$

The second piece yields

$$- \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n-1}}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{1+2z} \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {q+n-1\choose n-1} 
\frac{1}{(1+z)^{n-1-q}} \; dz
\\ = - \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {q+n-1\choose n-1} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^q}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{1+2z} \; dz
\\ = - \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {q+n-1\choose n-1} 
\sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} (-1)^{n-p} 2^{n-p}
\\ = - \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {q+n-1\choose n-1} (-1)^{n-q} 2^{n-q} 
\sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} (-1)^{q-p} 2^{q-p}
\\ = - (-1)^n \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {q+n-1\choose n-1} 2^{n-q}.$$

We see that the two pieces  from $w=0$ cancel so that the contribution
is zero. This  almost completes the proof, we only  need to choose the
contour so  that $w=1$ and $w=1+z$  are not included. For  the initial
geometric series  to converge we need  $|1+z|\epsilon\lt |1-w|\gamma.$
With  $\epsilon$  and  $\gamma$  in  a neigborhood  of  zero  we  have
$|1+z|\epsilon  \le  (1+\epsilon)\epsilon$ and  $(1-\gamma)\gamma  \le
|1-w|\gamma.$  The  series   converges  if  $(1+\epsilon)\epsilon  \lt
(1-\gamma)\gamma.$ Therefore  a good choice  is $\epsilon =  1/10$ and
$\gamma=1/5.$  The  contour in  $\gamma$  clearly  includes $w=0$  and
$w=-z$ and definitely does not include $w=1$ and $w=1+z$ with leftmost
value $9/10.$ This concludes the proof.

**Addendum, next day.** We are not required to simplify the sum                        that appears in $w=0,$ but we may do so. We get                                                                                                                                       $$S_n = \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {q+n-1\choose n-1} 2^{n-q}                                        = 2^n [z^{n-1}] \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{(1-z/2)^n}                                          \\ = (-1)^{n+1} 2^{2n}                                                                     \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^{n}}                                                         \frac{1}{z-1} \frac{1}{(z-2)^n}.$$                                                                                                                                                    Residues sum to zero and the residue at infinity is zero by inspection.                    The residue at $z=1$ contributes $-2^{2n}.$ The residue at $z=2$                           requires                                                                                                                                                                              $$\frac{1}{(2+(z-2))^n} \frac{1}{1+(z-2)} =                                                \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{1}{(1+(z-2)/2)^n} \frac{1}{1+(z-2)}.$$                                                                                                                            and we get the contribution                                                                                                                                                           $$(-1)^{n+1} 2^n \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {q+n-1\choose n-1} (-1)^q 2^{-q}                         (-1)^{n-1-q} = S_n.$$                                                                                                                                                                 This shows that $2 S_n - 2^{2n} = 0$ or $S_n = 2^{2n-1}.$

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It's far beyond me. I will try to understand your approach to the question!